# Getting error while deploy django apps in aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

> [Instance: i-*****************] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...) File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd) CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

i'm getting this error, can anyone give some picture of what and why it is coming.

And my requirements.txt is

Django==1.11.4, djangorestframework==3.5.1, psycopg2==2.7.3.1, gunicorn==19.7.0, django-cors-headers==2.1.0, whitenoise==3.3.1, coreapi==2.3.1, sendgrid==5.2.0, awsebcli==3.5.1, pystan==2.17.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements.txt should look like this:

```
Django==1.11.4
djangorestframework==3.5.1
psycopg2==2.7.3.1
gunicorn==19.7.0
django-cors-headers==2.1.0
whitenoise==3.3.1
coreapi==2.3.1
sendgrid==5.2.0
awsebcli==3.5.1
pystan==2.17.0.0
```

if you connect to your instance using

```
eb ssh
```

And then run

```
source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate
source /opt/python/current/env
pip install -r /opt/python/current/app/requirements.txt
```

You should get to see the errors.

Tom.

Comment: corrupted means ?

Comment: please see above

Comment: Same as in my project but i copy pasted like this.

Comment: are you installing the necessary prerequesitites using yum? Take a look at the example ebextensions file here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064290/issue-deploying-django-to-aws/47065045#47065045

Comment: only postgres is installing using yum. And this is my .config file ``container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "python manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
  02_collectstatic:
    command: "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"

option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "pms_backend.settings"
    PYTHONPATH: "$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: "pms_backend/wsgi.py"

packages:
  yum:
    postgresql95-devel: []
``

Comment: please try adding the other yum packages from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064290/issue-deploying-django-to-aws/47065045#47065045

Comment: pip can install this in virtual environment, why yum?

Comment: not everything can be installed by pip in elastic beanstalk unfortunately

Comment: Tried, error coming.``CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
``

Comment: please see above

Comment: Problem with the pip version, trying to upgrade that it throws permission denied error and i'm not able to use sudo & not able to change the folder permission.