# `eb deploy` error 'Your requirements.txt is invalid' (Python app)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

I have a Django 1.11 app I deploy on ElasticBeanstalk Python 2.7 platform. After updating some of my requirements, it seems `pip` is failing on EB. Weird because it works on my local Python 2.7.16 env (MacOS 10.15.1 default) just fine.

Here's the error shown in the EB application logs:

> [Instance: i-07622227350cdbc48] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...) File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd) CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I dove into the `eb-activity.log` and found a few lines where the cause for this `exit status 1` is mentioned. Specially:

```
...
error in enum-compat setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected version spec in enum34; python_version < "3.4" at ; python_version < "3.4"

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-0u2vRJ/enum-compat
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 20.0.2 is available.
...
```

And after searching around, I realized this is related to this issue: https://github.com/jstasiak/enum-compat/pull/4 (`enum-compat` is a requirement of one of my project's requirements, `intuit-oauth`). The fix to that issue caused older versions of `setuptools` to break when installing it, as explained in this [comment](https://github.com/jstasiak/enum-compat/pull/4#issuecomment-550086035).

That means `pip`! And as it can be seen in the log snippet above, for some reason **EB uses pretty [old versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platform-history-python.html)**. WHICH IS DUMB BUT OK.

Fortunately, there was an update available for my Python app platform (64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.4) on EB which although only goes up to `pip` 9 (out of 20...), was enough to solve this for me. Otherwise I would've had to use a preinit hook (via `.ebextensions` `files` field) to upgrade `pip`, or something annoying like that.

However, since the las deployment had failed, the platform upgrade also didn't work... I had to redeploy an old version that still worked first, then upgrade the Python platform, and THEN deploy my new code again.

> I also recommend this answer to debug other similar issues: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47093980/761963